# How to retrieve the Account id

Tags: apex, account, loop, method

I need to retrieve the Account id and insert it to my method. Get the Basket__r.Account__r.id and place it to the Account id inside the for loop. How can i do that?

```
list<Configuration__c> conf = [select id, name, Basket__r.id, Basket__r.Account__r.id  from Configuration__c where Basket__r.id = : basketId];
    
    
    for (Configuration__c confList: conf){
    
    Attachment att = [select id, body from Attachment where name like parentId = :confList.id];
    system.debug(att);
    system.debug(att.Body);
    system.debug(att.Body.toString()); 
    list <Guarantee_Line__c> guara = new list <Guarantee_Line__c>();
    
    guara = GuaranteeCreator.createGuarantee(att.Body.toString(), confList, Account id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your variable names (confList is not a list, and conf **is** a list), but aside from that, you just need to reference the account record as `<record>.Basket__r.Account__r`.

```
list<Configuration__c> confList = [select id, name, Basket__c, Basket__r.Account__r.Id  from Configuration__c where Basket__c = :basketId];
for (Configuration__c conf: confList){
    Attachment att = [select id, body from Attachment where name like parentId = :conf.id];
    list <Guarantee_Line__c> guara = GuaranteeCreator.createGuarantee(att.Body.toString(), conf, conf.Basket__r.Account__r);
}
```

Note that `Account__r` represents the account record (e.g. all fields you query through the relationship). You may need to add additional fields to your query.

Comment: thank you for the fixes! However, i did this an i get an error of incorrect signature. Maybe it's my method's issue. My method: public static list <Guarantee_Line__c> createGuarantee(String jsonStr, Configuration__c pConf, Account acc){

Comment: @Christos It's expecting an entire account, not an ID. This is different than your original question. I'll edit.

Comment: Thank you! Resolved it!